# Export mmtable from R

Tags: r, export

I am trying to export a generated mmtable either as .png or directly to the word.
I have already tried saveWidget and webshot. But any attempt is without success. Do you have any advice on how to export a mmtable, please?

```
library(mmtable2)
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
```

## 1.0 Data Transformation -----

```
data_wrangled <- mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, cyl) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c(cty, hwy), .fns = mean)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(cty, hwy),
    names_to = "fuel_economy_type",
    values_to = "fuel_economy"
  )

data_wrangled
```

## 2.0 Table Main ----

```
main_table <- data_wrangled %>%
  mutate(fuel_economy = round(fuel_economy, 1)) %>%
  
  mmtable(cells = fuel_economy, table_name = "Fuel Economy") +
  
  # Specify Headers
  header_top(manufacturer) +
  header_left(cyl) +
  header_left_top(fuel_economy_type) +
  
  
  # Specify formatting
  header_format(manufacturer, list(cell_text(transform = "capitalize"))) +
  header_format(fuel_economy_type, list(cell_text(transform = "uppercase"))) +
  table_format(
    locations = list(
      cells_body(rows = c(2, 6))
    ),
    style     = list(
      cell_borders(sides = "top", color = "grey")
    )
  )

main_table
saveWidget(main_table, "temp.html")
webshot("temp.html", "main_table.png", vwidth = 441, vheight = 351)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export your mmtable2 table with the gtsave function from the gt package.

Your codes should look something like this:

`gtsave(apply_formats(main_table), filename = "main_table.rtf")`

or

`gtsave(apply_formats(main_table), filename = "main_table.png")`